# How to run services in non-root user mode?

Tags: sudo, users

I have configured few init services in root-user mode. After that I have ran same script as non-root user mode, It fails with following error.

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to manage system services or units.
Authenticating as: Cloud User (ec2-user)
```

How to resolve without adding sudoers ? Ex: for tomcat we run as tomcat user(non-root mode)